# An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a demo application in .net MVC.

Below is the code snippet from my StudentController.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int studentId)
{
    var std = studentList.Where(s => s.StudentId == studentId).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(std);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Student std)
{
    //write code to update student 

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

code snippet from RouteConfig :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I hit url `http://localhost:54977/student/Edit/1` I am getting following exception.

`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'studentId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'MVC1.Controllers.StudentController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters`.

But it works fine when I hit url `http://localhost:54976/student/Edit?StudentId=1`.

I am new to .net MVC. Can anybody please suggest me on this.

Comment: Show your RouteMap setup please

Comment: I have added the same in my question..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue is due to your routing configuration.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The third parameter in http://localhost:54977/student/Edit/1 gets mapped to {id} not to studentId.

You have two options to solve the issue:

1) Change your parameter name

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
        var std = studentList.Where(s => s.StudentId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(std);
    }
```

2) Add new route for Edit:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.MapRoute(
            "EditStudent",
            "Edit/{StudentId}",
            new { controller = "Student", action = "Edit" });
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Student",                                           // Route name
                "Edit/{StudentId}",                            // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Student", action = "Edit" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Without config routes

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: '/Student/Edit?StudentId='1,
                dataType: 'json',
                ...
                ...
                ..
```